# run class file from an rpm

Tags: java, maven, rpm

I created a `.rpm` file out of maven from a Java project. When I extract the rpm it has all .class files. Now I want to run a specific `.class file.` Say rpm name is `test_maven.rpm.` Class file is in the path `/home/workspace/abc/Application.class` inside `rpm.` How to run this file in the same location as rpm and also from different location ? If I run it from different location how will I mention the rpm to run the class file from ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Run the class file from the rpm `%post` script? Run it by hand after installation? Run it in a script?

Comment: This is what I'm ding exactly. I have a Spring-Boot application. I want to create rpm out of Maven build and trying to create a .sh file. In the .sh file I wanted to invoke Application.java. I was trying to install the rpm and start the service as "service 'projectName' start" but it was not working. But when I create a tar.gz file out of Maven and run build rpm from tar.gz file and spec file I'm able to start service as said above.

Comment: Create an init script/service file/systemd unit file as appropriate and install it to the correct location via the `%install` and `%files` sections. Once that's done you should be able to just use `service` in `%post` to start the service **but** I **strongly** suggest you **do not** do that. Leave starting the service up to the admin installing the service don't do it automatically. The system the package is being installed on may not be ready to run the service yet when the package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

> RPM Package Manager (also known simply as RPM), originally called the Red-hat Package Manager, is a program for installing, uninstalling, and managing software packages in Linux.

RPM is not inteded to run the binary/program, only to manage the installation of software alongwith versioning and dependency checking.

You have to create a shell script file to run your java program and bundled this script file into the RPM file.